# Bubble - content overflowing

Tags: html, css

I've created a bubble in css3, but in some browsers (specifically Windows Safari 5.1.7) my span overflows my anchor tag, even though 1) it's positioned relative and 2) had a static width / height with a hidden overflow. In all other browsers (Firefox, IE, Chrome) it looks fine but the anchor link (hover) extends outside the bubble, to the width of the `span` since it is displayed block.

My question is, why is it overflowing and how can I fix it? I thought using a relative position with an absolute element sort of put it back into place, is this not correct?

Here's a [JSFiddle of the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/9rj9E/) at hand. The code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body    {background-color: #ccc;}
        a       {display: block; -moz-border-radius: 10em; -webkit-border-radius: 10em; border-radius: 10em; border: 5px solid #eee; width: 220px; height: 220px; overflow: hidden; position: relative; text-align: center; line-height: 24px; font-size: 20px; color: #fff; background-color: #fff;}
        .content{display: block; position: absolute; bottom: 0px; background-color: #000; width: 100%; padding: 20px 0 30px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <span class="content">
            Test<br />
            Bubble
        </span>
    </a>
</body>
```

Here's an example I keep running into on chrome, if I hover the Green (padding) or Blue (width) my mouse goes into a pointer, which is not where the link should be with `overflow: hidden` - it's outside the rounded corners.

[image]

Comment: the anchor link is not overflowing into the span. the a link contains the span block element.. i dont understand the question

Comment: working fine for me in safari 6.

Comment: @nol in specific browsers (Safari) the red extends outside the rounded corers to the full width of the anchor. In other browsers (Chrome, IE) the red does not but the pointer (if you hover the bubble at the bottom right, outside the rounded corner) shows up, which it shouldn't.

Comment: your fiddle looks fine in my Safari (7.0.3, OSX 1.9.2). And what red? Are you sure you posted the correct code?

Comment: ok so here is what i think will fix it .. the overflow doesn't seem to work so you need a radius on the span here http://jsfiddle.net/9rj9E/3/ very interesting though

Comment: :/ that doesn't seem to work in the latest version of chrome. I even tried putting a relative container surrounding my anchor which also didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO here is what I figured out.. overflow hidden doesn't work with links, just hides it visually

http://jsfiddle.net/88UeR/

its only visual not clipping of the block level element

```
#a {
position:absolute;
border-radius:100px;
background-color:#72CEE0;
width:100px;
height:100px;
left:150px;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

so if you want to hide it completely you have to make the inside element not overflow outside the parent for anything other than to visually hide it

Comment: I appreciate the help and I may go with this option if no others show up but from an SEO standpoint this isn't very optimal. The `overflow: hidden;` works on the top portion of the link in my fiddle but not the bottom, where the span is.